# How can I pass an arbitrary object via a CloudQueueMessage?

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, azure-queues

I have a `CloudQueueMessage` and I want to insert "Hello World" - so I write:

```
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("Hello World");
```

it’s perfect.

My problem is that I want to put an object in place of "Hello World" like this:

```
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(new MyObject(parameter1, parameter2, ...));
```

But the compiler will not let me because it tells me:

```
The constructor CloudQueueMessage (MyObject) is undefined.
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing object messages in Azure Queue Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550702/passing-object-messages-in-azure-queue-storage)

Answer (score 0):

`CloudQueueMessage` may be constructed with either binary data or a string, not an object to be serialized (though you may serialize it to a string yourself, then store it as a message). That's why you're getting an error: there's no constructor that takes a `MyObject` as its parameter.

For more details on the creation of a CloudQueueMessage, see [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueuemessage_members.aspx).

Comment: So what are you doing?? must i have to use stringa?

Comment: It's really up to you, but strings are quite easy. You're talking about messages, not object storage, so it's very simple. For me, I usually create a simple tokenized string with a simple delimiter. For instance, I might be creating thumbnails and my message might look like: `"THUMB|BLOBURL|THUMBURL"` - trivial to string-split and parse. You can also go back and modify a message (let's say it's a multi-pass video rendering; you can leave a marker with the pass completed, so in case the task fails, you can restart where you left off).

Answer (score 0):

You may check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550702/passing-object-messages-in-azure-queue-storage).

It outlines a technique for having "Strongly typed Queues" using C#. However the approach is really trivial, and I am sure you can achieve a similar behavior in Java. As long as you can serialize your object to a binary array.

[This is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array) that might help you, if you need to. And [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837698/converting-any-object-to-a-byte-array-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I utilize for serializing objects to strings and back for when dealing with Azure Queues.  Just make sure that your objects are small, so that they fit within the 64k requirement

```
protected CloudQueueMessage CreateCloudQueueMessage(TQueueableEntity message)
{
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TQueueableEntity));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, message);

        return new CloudQueueMessage(stringWriter.ToString());
    }
}

protected TQueueableEntity CreateObjectFromMessage(CloudQueueMessage message)
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TQueueableEntity));

    //Deserialize message
    using (var reader = new StringReader(message.AsString))
    {
        var result = (TQueueableEntity)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: 64K message limit now with 1.6 SDK